# Which method would get triggered in AppDelegate when we press the home button and after using some other application return back to that application

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift3, appdelegate

This is my first question on stack overflow so bear with it. 
I am making a single view app using `WKWebView`. Which simply loads the web app, using `url` 
**What I am doing and What I want, I have explained everything below** 
**Xcode version: 11.7** 
**iOS Version: 13.7** 
Here is the `Outlet` in `ViewController`.

```
@IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!
```

This `webView` get loads by calling the following function in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
func loadMoma() {

    if let safeUrl = URL(string: url) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: safeUrl)
        webView.load(request)
    }
}
```

Here is my `viewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    check = ConnectivityCheck.Connection()
    
    if check {
        loadMoma()
    }

}
```

Here `ConnectivityCheck.Connection()` returns the true if there is access to internet and false if there is not.
Using this check `loadMoma()` gets called. 
And if there is no connection nothing happens & in the `viewDidAppear()` method, `Alert` function gets called, here's code for this.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if !check {
        self.Alert(Message: "Connection error!, please enable the Internet.")
    }
}
```

Definition of `Alert()` method :-

```
func Alert (Message: String){
    
     let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Connectivity.", message: Message, preferredStyle: .alert)
           
           let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Go to settings", style: .default) { (action) in
               
                if let settingsUrl = URL.init(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(settingsUrl)
                }
               
           }
           
           
           alert.addAction(action)
           
           present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}
```

This causes Alert and a button to navigate to setting of iPhone to enable internet.
[Output of Alert method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9dU7.png)

## What I want

When user returns from settings to app, in the `AppDelegate`, `loadMoma()` method should get called.
For this I have created an instance of `ViewController` in class `AppDelegate` like this :-

```
var vc = ViewController()
```

I called `loadMoma` in `applicationWillEnterForeground` like this:-

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("applicationWillEnterForeground")
    if !flag {
        vc.loadMoma()
    }
}
```

Where `flag` is same as `check`.
But the thing is even print is not getting triggered when I press home button or navigate to settings while running app.

Please let me know where should I put `vc.loadMoma()` in `AppDelegate` to get the functionality that I described above.

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: applicationWillEnterForeground will be triggered when the app is in the foreground state.
Get the current root view controller from the window object.
like this.
guard let yourvc = self.window?.rootViewController  as? YourVC else { return }
do your reload work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using iOS version 13.7 and Xcode version 11.7, you should have to use Scene delegates life cycle methods to get it done your requirements.

Whenever user comes back into your app from other apps, SceneDelegate's sceneWillEnterForeground and sceneDidBecomeActive methods will become fired. So, you can place your code for internet connectivity check and calling a loadMoma() method inside sceneWillEnterForeground method.

#HappyCoding

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the code you want to execute on app open in applicationDidBecomeActive, and the code you want ran on exit, in applicationDidEnterBackground, in the App Delegate.